# SQL Server Convert scientific notation (exponential notation) string to numeric

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to understand the following T-SQL statement:

```sql
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(16) = N'1.377532E-39';
SELECT  @s AS [orig]
  , CONVERT(REAL, @s) AS [real]
  , CONVERT(FLOAT, @s) AS [float]
  -- , CONVERT(NUMERIC(2, 0), @s) AS [numeric direct] 
    /* does not work: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5 */
  , CONVERT(NUMERIC(2, 0), CONVERT(FLOAT, @s)) AS [numeric via float];
```

My desired output is a value with `NUMERIC(2,0)` precision (in this case 0). Direct conversion does not work; I have to convert from `NVARCHAR` to `FLOAT` first and then from `FLOAT` to `NUMERIC(2,0)`.

Direct conversion works if the string does not contain a scientific notation number. I would like to understand **why**? Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, it is simply a matter of the [Float datatype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) being able to convert a string representing scientific notation to a number, whereas the [Numeric datatype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) cannot. Once Float has converted a number out of scientific notation into a number (as opposed to a string that represents a number), then Numeric can handle the conversion.

In the documentation for the [Float](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) and [Numeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) datatypes, there is reference in both to the use of scientific notation, but this is to define the minimum and maximum values accepted by the datatype. In the Float documentation, it is stated that:

```
Conversion of float values that use scientific notation to decimal or
numeric is restricted to values of precision 17 digits only. Any value 
with precision higher than 17 rounds to zero.
```

This indicates that Float can interpret scientific notation whereas Decimal and Numeric datatypes can only handle a number with a maximum precision of 17 resulting from a number specified using scientific notation.

I hope that makes sense. Leave a comment if you have any questions.

Comment: So, when I am trying SELECT CAST(5.68579E+17 AS numeric) , then getting the result as 568579000000000000 . But in excel the value is showing as 568579480918736000.