# Convert scientific E notation to a decimal value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2019 and have a column with decimal values but sometimes source sends data with scientific E notation. I tried the below query to convert with a value specified and that works as expected.

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(6E-06 AS DECIMAL(18, 9)) AS OutCol;
SELECT TRY_CAST(-6E-06 AS DECIMAL(18, 9)) AS OutCol;
```

Output:

```
0.000006000
-0.000006000
```

But, when I use it with my table its unable to convert. I get `NULL`. `MyCol` is of `nvarchar` datatype.

```
SELECT TRY_CAST(MyCol AS DECIMAL(18, 9)) AS OutCol
FROM Test;
```

Comment: What is the data type of `MyCol`? I suspect it is a string based data type. `-6E-06` and `'-6E-06'` are *not* the same value and `TRY_CAST('6E-06' AS DECIMAL(18, 9))` returns `NULL`.

Comment: *"`MyCol` is of `nvarchar` datatype."* Yep, there's the issue; your test isn't a fair comparison, as you are comparing a `float` to a `decimal` not an `nvarchar` representing a float to a `decimal`. Convert the value to a `float` first, and then a `decimal`.

Comment: @ThomA Right, when I convert it to string it returns `NULL`.

Comment: You should probably fix that so you're not storing numeric values in string columns. We have numeric types precisely so we can avoid this kind of problem. Anyway, `float` is a little more forgiving, but could introduce accuracy issues: `SELECT TRY_CONVERT(decimal(18,9), TRY_CONVERT(float, MyCol))...` Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39534546/20091109).

Answer (score 2):

You should probably fix that so you're not storing numeric values in string columns. We have numeric types precisely so we can avoid this kind of problem.

Anyway, `float` is a little more forgiving, and unlike `decimal`, can accept strings in scientific notation. But note that it could introduce accuracy issues:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(decimal(18,9), TRY_CONVERT(float, MyCol))...
```

[Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/R99123Z0). Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39534546/20091109).

Answer (score 1):

The `6E-06` and `-6E-06` in the question example are **already binary literals**. You'll get same results in your test if you run it like this:

```
SELECT TRY_CAST('6E-06' AS DECIMAL(18, 9)) AS OutCol;
SELECT TRY_CAST('-6E-06' AS DECIMAL(18, 9)) AS OutCol;
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't have built-in support for directly converting to numeric or decimal types from strings formatted in scientific notation. Therefore your best option is probably **pre-processing** this data. Failing that, you're left with some [rather complex code.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6750771/3043), but you might be able to simplify things by converting to a `float` or `real` first, depending on the possible range of the data.